# gcloud filter result based on time

Tags: bash, datetime, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to list machine Images on GCP and filter out results based on CreatimeTimestamp - a few hours/days.
I'm trying to do something like this :

```
gcloud beta compute machine-images list --sort-by "creationTimestamp" --project=XXXXX --format="table(name,creationTimestamp.date('%Y-%m-%d-%T'))" --filter="CREATION_TIMESTAMP.date('%Y-%m-$d-%H:%M:%S')<'$(date -d '3 hours ago' "+%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S")'"
```

To list 3 hours old machine-images

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ###### Update
>
> Thinking more about your question, I think there's probably an easier way than my answer (below). The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters) suggests that you can do a date compare directly. So, perhaps:
>
> ```sh
> WHEN=$(date +%s --date='3 hours ago')
> gcloud beta compute machine-images list \
> --project=${PROJECT} \
> --format="table(name,creationTimestamp)") \
> --filter="creationTimestamp.date(\"+%s\")>${WHEN}"
> ```

`gcloud` filter doesn't include a shell and so you can't include e.g. bash's `date` command in the filter.

I think (!) the way to do this is to `format` output the results you want and then filter.

```sh
IMAGES=$(gcloud beta compute machine-images list \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="csv[no-heading](name,creationTimestamp.date())")

for IMAGE in ${IMAGES}
do
  IFS=, read NAME TIMESTAMP <<< ${IMAGE}
  CREATED=$(date +%s --date=${TIMESTAMP}
  WHEN=$(date +%s --date='3 hours ago')
  if [ ${CREATED} -gt ${WHEN} ]
  then
    printf "Image: %s (Creation: %s)\n" NAME TIMESTAMP
  fi
done
```